# blank area on render

Tags: rendering

Every time I try to render this image, half of it doesn't render. I don't have a render region so I don't know what's happening. Does anybody have a fix?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your render clearly says that it has just finished 0 of 4 tiles. Meaning the one it is rendering is the first of 4. It also says you just waited 1:46 minutes so far but the render will take about 2:38 hours.

[image: render times]

If you have left Blender mostly at default settings, then you will see in the *Render Properties* under *Performance* > *Memory* that *Use Tiling* is enabled, and the *Tile Size* is set to 2048:

[image: tile size]

Usually when rendering standard 1920 × 1080 images you will not notice the tiling. So I assume (although you did not give any information on that) you are rendering a 4k image with a resolution of 3840 × 2160 pixels. This is larger than the tile size and will be split up in 4 tiles, from which it started rendering the first one from the bottom left with the full size of 2048 × 2048, and the other three will be rendered with what is left from the complete image resolution:

[image: tiling 4k image]

So to sum it up: there is nothing broken here, no need to fix anything. Of course you could set the *Tile Size* to something larger like 4096 so that the complete image can be rendered in one tile. That depends on your hardware if it is capable of rendering such large tiles and if it really is in any way faster than rendering it in 4 tiles...