# how to change Rendering Tile in cycle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using Blender 4.0 and  i saw the rendering tile in cycles hs changed. While I am  using older version there are lots of small number of tiles while rendering a image in cycle. But In 4.0 version there is something called 0/4 rendered tiles with one big tile as shown in pic .How Can i change to old setting which gives rendering tiles like 2.8 version?

[image]

Comment: Since Cycles X update, the tile size isn't supposed to matter so much, and cpu and gpu can work together on the same tile with no issues etc.

Comment: It looks like you're rendering a 4k image. The default tile size is 2048, so it will not be rendered in one tile. This setting exists for quite a long time now and is not new in 4.0, maybe you have not rendered in 4k before? Or in older versions you had the default options changed to either a larger tile size or disabled "Use Tiling"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [blank area on render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304311/blank-area-on-render)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your tile size may have defaulted to Blender's current default tile size, 2048 pixels. To change this, in the Properties window, go to Render >  Performance > Memory > Tile Size (Use Tiling should be checked).

[image]

The number of render tiles is determined by the resolution size of each tile and how many will be needed to fill the pixel area of the render resolution. For example, if your render tiles are 100 pixels and you render a 2000x1000px image, it will need 200 render tiles. See below:

(render WxH divided by tile WxH: 2000x1000/100x100 = 200)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your formula works in your example, but not in general, since render tiles are square and images probably not. For example, the original problem of the question: rendering a 4k image (3840×2160) with the default tile size of 2048. Your formula says you need (3840×2160)/2048² ≈ 1.98, so 2 full tiles. But you need 4. With $w$, $h$ the width and height of the image and $t$ the tile size, the formula is _number of tiles_ = $\lceil w/t\rceil × \lceil h/t\rceil$.

Comment: True, good call on the updated formula. The example I gave was an easy one to illustrate the concept of pixel 'area' needing to be calculated by tiles. In your example with a 4k image, Blender will say it needs to render 4 tiles, but only one of them will be a full 2048. The other three will total the remaining image area, which will be less than 2048². What all of this means practically is that the time it takes to process that first tile will be much longer than the next 3, so to optimize your tiles for the best memory savings, you'll probably want a more even spread of smaller tiles.

Comment: That's correct, the other 3 tiles will render quicker. But with the introduction of _Cycles X_ I didn't see a big improvement when decreasing the tile size to make them fit more evenly into the render size. _Cycles X_ with modern GPUs simply renders faster with larger tiles, so if your hardware can handle it, it might even be better if you switched the tile size to 4096, then even 4k images are rendered in a single tile. For the default size of 1920×1080 a tile size of 2048 is sufficient for all renders with 100% or less (for example test renders etc.).

Comment: For illustrating the concept - I voted to close this question as a duplicate because this has already been explained here a few times...

Comment: Wonderful insight. Very valuable information.